# How can I customize Xamarin Studio toolbar?

Tags: customization, toolbar, xamarin-studio

I really miss toolbar from Visual Studio in XS, and I would like to customize it -- adding "save"/"save all" buttons for sure, but also removing completely useless (for me) ones as well.

Can I customize XS toolbar? If yes, how?

Comment: What version of XS are you using?
What buttons are useless and you would like to remove?
Why don't you use shortcuts like Ctrl(Cmd)+S and Ctrl(Cmd)+Shift+S?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XS at this moment doesn't have ability to add commands to toolbar(tbh shouldn't be hard to implement).

But it's very easy to add it if you create AddIn:
Just add this to AddIn manifest.addin.xml:

```
<Extension path = "/MonoDevelop/Ide/CommandBar">
    <ItemSet id = "MyCommandsBar">
        <CommandItem id = "MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.Save" />
        <CommandItem id = "MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.FileCommands.SaveAll" />
    </ItemSet>
</Extension>
```

And call:

```
IdeApp.Workbench.ShowCommandBar ("MyCommandsBar");
```

Result will be:
[image]

**Update:**
To address your question in comment.

Unfortunately you will have to create actual AddIn(Plugin), to do this you will have to install "AddInMaker addin" from online AddIn Gallery.

Then create new AddIn project and add this logic. You can't just change some config files to do this.

I created GitHub repository with this sample, see this commit to see changes needed: https://github.com/DavidKarlas/SaveButtonsAddIn/commit/7cff0bd9eadfa5c02f5a7d21c5b139e13e50d860

Notice that I also added StartupHandler that is executed when Xamarin Studio is started.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry for naive questions, but where should I place this file (currently I saved it to "\AppData\Roaming\XamarinStudio-5.0\Config") and how should I call this command? Btw. I use XS 5.10+Windows.

Comment: I'm still wondering... What buttons are useless and you would like to remove?

Comment: Thank you again, it works, but I need one XS to launch add-in which launches second one with the toolbar. I read https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/extending_xamarin_studio_with_addins/ and couldn't find any information how to use this add in on the first launch of XS. Well, for me, search edit box and platform combo are useless, I don't use them so often (or at all) it would justify having them in toolbar.

Comment: Use "mdtool setup pack SaveButtonsAddIn.dll" in cmd inside bin\Debug folder, that will create .mpack file, then inside your XS go to AddIn manager and use "Install from file..."(bottom left corner).

About Platform combo... Maybe we could hide that if you got only 1 configuration...

About useless search... Add keybinding to "Go to File..." command and use it and type some file name(you can use fuzzy search). You won't have to use Solution pad ever again to open files ;)

Comment: Once again thank you very much. It works, you are great! :-) As for search -- I use it for searching only, and here I would prefer having a pad (pane), not a popup. It is because I switch constantly between modes. Besides... better than deciding which shoe size is best for everyone is allowing users to customize "the shoe" :-)